# To solve $x\geq\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To solve $x\geq\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Do i have to make cases like if $x \in [0,1] $ and if $x<0$ and then square accordingly or what is way to do this?'

Thanks

Comment: That's the right idea; the inequality holds $\iff x^2 \geq 1-x^2 \iff 2x^2 \geq 1$, etc.

Comment: i am bit confused abot how to make cases. Do i have to split at x=1

Comment: Assuming you are limited to real numbers (which you must be if you have order) we know $x\ge sqrt {} \ge 0$  so you can square both sides to get $x^2\ge 1-x^2$ so $x^2 \ge 1/2$.  As we know $x $ is non negative we can take the sqrt of both side.  But we are also restricted to $1-x^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: What I mean to say, is in this case, x <0 is impossible so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: If you just draw a picture with the graphs $y=x$ (straight line) and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (semi-circle) in the same coordinate system, it should be pretty obvious what the answer is (and what computations you need to do to verify it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to square it, because the square function is monotonic on $[0,\infty]$ you just need to make sure both sides are non-negative.  As the square root on the right is non-negative, we have $x \ge 0$, so go ahead and square.

Comment: But do i have to split at $x=1$

Comment: @J.Deff:  No, why would you have to?  You can't have $x \ge 1$ because the square root becomes imaginary.  You do have to check that you have not introduced extraneous solutions by squaring, such as $x \ge 1$

Comment: Can you give complete detailed solutiuon

Comment: Yes, I can.  No, I won't.

Comment: haha thats funny

Comment: Look at what you have been told here and try to solve it.  If you show some effort, we can help some more.